# PHP Test Copy Script

Tags: php

I am testing a PHP copy script on a hosted shared server using copy tool however the test.txt file is not being copied.

```
<?php 

$src = "/public_html/accounts";
$dst = "/public_html/accounts/myDirectory";
copy($src . '/' . 'test.txt', $dst . '/' . 'test.txt');

?>
```

I asked my service provider if the server has the copy tool and they confirmed that the server does have copy command, how can I debug this to see what the problem is?

[image]

Regards

Comment: Step 1: check error logs for more information. Step 2: ascertain files exist.

Comment: do echo file_get_contents($src . '/' . 'test.txt'); and check if the file's contents does come up, if not, your path is invalid

Comment: If you do not have user input, you can just use the command line right? *public_html*? seems like you do not have user input.

Comment: OK, I enabled PHP error logging from cpanel and noticed that public_html is in /home/<user>/public_html, I can't see /home directory via FTP client nor can I change directory to it: Response: 550 Can't change directory to /home: No such file or directory, using this absolute file path works though